# Stop Javascript function execution upon a click event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a div named "header". I want it endlessly  to go from opacity 0.1 to opacity 1 and then fade back to opacity 0.1 unless it is clicked; in that case I want to stop the above cycle.

```
$('#header').fadeTo( 4000, 1.0 ); 
$('#header').fadeTo( 4000, 0.1 );
```

So, I want the above to be in a function which will repeat the two orders until "header" is clicked.
How may I realise that?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this.  The multiple animations can use the animation queue so one follows the other and then use the completion function of the last one to start the cycle over again.

To stop, it you can just use jQuery's `.stop()` which will stop the current animation and clear the queue.

For completeness, I then set the opacity to a known value after the animation is stopped.

```
function fadeHeader() {
    $('#header').fadeTo( 4000, 1.0 ).fadeTo( 4000, 0.1, fadeHeader); 
}

// start the repeating animation
fadeHeader();

// stop the animation upon a click
$('#header').click(function() {
    $(this).stop(true).css("opacity", "1.0");
});
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/ctgLk/

Comment: It works; however as far as the browser understands(?) the recursion it becomes very slow to load the page and sometimes it does not respond at all...

Comment: @ILIAS - you must have something else going on in your page because the above code doesn't cause the browser to go unresponsive.  See the jsFiddle example I've added to my answer.  Are you sure that you aren't calling `fadeHeader()` more than once?

Comment: Everything is okay now. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
var headerclicked = false;

function doheadercheck()
{
  if(!headerclicked)
  {
    if("#header").hasClass("fadein"))
    {
      //Fade out
      $("#header").removeClass("fadein").fadeTo(4000,0.1,doheadercheck);
    }
    else
    {
      //Fade in
      $("#header").addClass("fadein").fadeTo(4000,1,doheadercheck);
    }
  }
}

doheadercheck();
$("#header").click(function()
{
  headerclicked = true;
  $("#header").stop(true).fadeTo(250,1);
});
```

Try like this :)

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a little [example](http://jsfiddle.net/XgFw2) to answer your question.

```
var stop = false;

var myFadeIn = function () {
    if (!stop) {
        $('#header').fadeIn(1000, myFadeOut);
    }
};

var myFadeOut = function () {
    if (!stop) {
        $('#header').fadeOut(1000, myFadeIn);
    }
};

$(document).ready(function() {
    myFadeOut();
    $('#header').click(function () {
        stop = true;
    });
});
```

Basically you can write two functions to fade in the div and fade it out, that call back each other at the end of each animation.  Then you attach a click callback to break the callback loop.  Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use [jQuery animate API](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)

```
function animation(){
    $("#header")
        .animate({opacity: 0.1}, {duration: "slow"})
        .animate({opacity: 1.0}, {duration: "slow", done: animation});
}


$(function() {
    $("#header").click( function(){ $(this).stop(true); } );
    animation();
});
```

Check the [jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/fguillen/Wpt5j/)